# making vba macro more efficient

Tags: excel, vba, macros

This macro looks at a row, copies the content and pastes it into desired cells in certain sheets.

I´d like to make this macro code quicker because it takes too long.
The code loops over about 7000 rows.

Any help would be appreciated,

Here´s my code:

```
Sub Input_Template()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Do

'Qc Note
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G8,C6").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
Range("C6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(R[2]C[4], ""DN"")"

'Supplier Name
Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G11").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

'RTV Number
Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G16,C22").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

'Cost
Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G9,G22,G24,G26,G27").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

'Supplier Code
Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G10").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

'PO Number
Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G7").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

'Suppplier Email
Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G15").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

'Address
 Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("C9").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

 Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("C10").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

 Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("C11").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

 Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("C12").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

 Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("C13").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

 Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("C14").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

 Sheets("Cost Gained").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("C15").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

Range("G9").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

Range("G15").Select
Selection.Style = "Hyperlink"

This contains code to add bold around an area, change font to arial size 16. 
But is very long so I have left it out.

'Save as pdf once finish one row, then save pdf in a location then continue until row 299.
    Sheets("Debit Note").Select
    ChDir "P:\Perkins\Quality\COPQ\J Benge COPQ\MACROS\Debit Notes\"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "P:\Perkins\Quality\COPQ\J Benge COPQ\MACROS\Debit Notes\" & Range("G8").Value
    'Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("Cost Gained").Select

ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -17).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Loop Until ActiveCell.Row = "299"

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of copying C11 then C12 then C13 etc why not copy C11:C15 in one go?  `Range("C11:C15").Copy`.

Comment: Don't think you will ever need the line `ActiveCell.Select`, its active because it is selected already.

Comment: What could i have instead of ActiveCell ?   I'm new to this, so i tried to make as easy as possible to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You shoul get rid of the `.Select` and `Selection.` you don´t need them, they slow down code and can cause errors.

For Example:

Instead of

```
Sheets("Debit Note").Select
Range("G11").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
```

You can write

```
Sheets("Debit Note").Range("G11").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Ive tried to take out the select. 
It comes up with run time error 1004. I highlights
Activecell.offset(1,-17).Select.

Comment: If you don´t use `.Select` you can´t work with `ActiveCell` either. But you can write `Cell(1,1).offset(1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Just add these two lines at the beginning of `Input_Template()`

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And add these two lines before the `End Sub`

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: What does the calculation=x1calculationManual / auto do?

Comment: It withholds the calculations of excel formulas, until your script is done, thus gaining performance increase

Answer (score 0):

As you're not using any of the `PasteSpecial` paste types (such as `xlPasteValues`) then you could just use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Gained").Cells(1, 2).Copy _
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Debit Note").Cells(2, 1)
```

This copies from range `B1` ( *.Cells(1,2)* - row 1, column 2) to `A2` ( *.cells(2,1)* - row 2, column 1).

Comment: at first i used just paste, then came up with errors so i used pastespecial, this seemed to work. I then tried to use xlpastevalues this came up with errors so ive just left it as pastespecial to the time being.